# Apply CSS only to inner-most element of same class as parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I have an XML file that's structured as such (line numbers added for clarity).

```xml
1.  <myclass>
2.      <myclass>
3.          <myclass>
4.              <inner1>
5.              <inner2>
6.      <myclass>
7.          <myclass>
8.              <inner1>
9.              <inner2>
10.     <myclass>
11.         <inner1>
12.         <inner2>
```

I don't have control over the XML file, it's structured this way and I can't do anything about it. I need to apply a style to the inner most `myclass` elements (lines 3, 7, 10). All innermost `myclass` elements will have `inner1` and `inner2` children.

Applying a style, such as `border` to `myclass`, will cause stacked borders.

Currently, I'm preprocessing the XML by parsing through it and adding an `innermost-myclass` class to the parent of all `inner1` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this without JS, though if you were open to it, there is a somewhat simple way of doing it in JS.

If it's of a fixed depth, you could check if the parent of the parent's class is also 'myclass'. If not, you could check if the div has children with 'myclass' or not.

Comment: I changed my approach to be a little faster by adding ```innermost-myclass``` to the parent of every ```inner1```.

Comment: In that case, you just have to do something like:
innermost-myclass{
 //style here
}

Comment: Right, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it w/o scripting.

Comment: Oh, that's just a css script, not JS.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath-1.0 expression to select all innermost `myclass` elements which have `inner1` and `inner2` children is

```
//myclass[inner1 and inner2]
```

But according to [this table for CSS/XPath equivalents](https://johnresig.com/blog/xpath-css-selectors/), it is not possible to realize this in CSS3:

```
Goal                    CSS 3              XPath
All Elements            *                  //*
All P Elements          p                  //p
All Child Elements      p > *              //p/*
Element By ID           #foo               //*[@id=’foo’]
Element By Class        .foo               //*[contains(@class,’foo’)] 1
Element With Attribute  *[title]           //*[@title]
First Child of All P    p > *:first-child  //p/*[0]
All P with an A child   Not possible       //p[a]  <!-- This line would be relevant -->
Next Element            p + *              //p/following-sibling::*[0]
```

So, I guess you have to look for another way to realize this.

Comment: It may be interesting to note, that, with XPath 3.1, the *"Element By Class"* item could be safely expressed with `//*[contains-token(@class,’foo’)]`. One may think, that `//*[@class='foo']` should suffice, but that won't match `@class` attributes, that contain multiple tokens, such as `class="foo bar batz"`. Resig's (linked) post is from 2005, that was before XPath 3.1.